# Laravel 5.6 разграничение прав пользователей

Tags: laravel

тут такое дельце, короче разбираюсь сижу тут с ларой, дошел то того что нужно как-то разграничить функционал, ну чтоб Были админы, модераторы, и все такое, пошел соответственно в документацию читаю аутентификацию и авторизацию и тут я понял что нихрена не понял. В общем как создать политики понятно, проверка тоже понятно, но не понятно как назначить пользователю тот или иной доступ, если у меня 1000 всяких модеров и админов как им назначить доступ, роль, или как вы их там называете, вот этого я не понял, я не слишком пока хорошо знаю английский но читать в принципе могу, поэтому возможно где-то что-то пропустил, в общем тыкните куда нить чтоб я в этом разобрался. Спасибо =)

Comment: Если трудности с английским, вот ссылка на русскоязычную документацию - https://laravel.ru/docs/v5

Comment: Тут вроде свежее дока: http://laravel.su/docs/5.4/authorization

Answer (score 2):

Если тяжело понять, то попробуйте два самых популярных пакета для ролей:

- https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust
- https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission

Comment: Интересно, обязательно попробую, просто меня бесит если чего-то не смог)